# Buying a CO2 tyre inflater

Tags: tire, repair, pump, co2

I am thinking about buying a CO2 tyre inflater. I have never used one before and have 3 questions:

1. Do they have enough pressure to get a road tyre up to full pressure (~100psi)
2. When you use a cartridge, do you have to use the entire cartridge at once?
3. Are there any common cartridge standards? i.e. am a better off going with a particular brand because it is compatible with more brands of cartridges.. or are they all happy to mix and match?

Comment: Related: [What are advantages and disadvantages of CO2 inflators over frame pumps?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/699/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-co2-inflators-over-frame-pumps)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes, this is no problem, though I would suggest practicing once before you have to use it on a flat. The first couple of times I used an inflator I had trouble inflating my tire fully.
2. No, but I've found that once I start a cartridge it will leak slowly, so it doesn't last forever. In my experience it doesn't last more than a few hours, certainly not more than a day.
3. You can buy inflators that handle both threaded and unthreaded. For example, this one -- [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00278XO0Q](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00278XO0Q) -- can take any 16g CO2 cartridge.

Comment: I've been able to use a partially-used CO2 cartridge months after the initial use. If yours are losing air, it's due to a faulty nozzle.

Comment: I never realized that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. No.
3. Threaded and unthreaded.